# Can you prevent default-push, but allow pull?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, push, dvcs

I want to know if there's a way to turn off the default push, but keep the default pull when using Mercurial.  I don't want to accidentally pollute the master repository by inadvertently pushing from an experimental repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution probably is the quickest and is certainly effective.  If there's any *official* way it would be using a `preoutgoing` hook:

```
[hooks]
preoutgoing = bash -c 'read -p "Really push to $HG_URL? " -n 1 RESP ; [ "$RESP" == "y" ]'
```

which will ask you if you want to push and provide the URL to which it would go as a reminder.

Comment: Hey, I really like this one, it's similar to Martin's, but gives me the option to continue when I manually type the url on the command line.  If you can tell me how to do that in powershell, we're in business.

Comment: I think the command to do complex scripting in powershell is wubi.exe.   By which I mean, sorry, I dont know powershell. ;)

Comment: I did quite a bit of experimenting, but couldn't quite get it to work. I'll keep plugging away and update here if I solve it.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve this by putting the following in my `.hg/hgrc` file, but I was wondering if there's a better/official way.

```
[paths]
default = http://server/hg/repo
default-push = .
```

Comment: This answer almost works, or, rather, mostly works, but can break if "." contains a repo - e.g. if you hg your home directory.  I fleshed it out a bit below to avoid such a problem.

Comment: @KrazyGlew I don't think that's necessary.  He said he's doing this in `.hg/hrc` so it's in repo and thus relative to the repo root, so that would always be `pushing to itself` which should never do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I like your own answer of setting `paths.default-push = .` -- it is simple and it is clear that it will work.

Another option would be a pre-push hook:

```
[hooks]
pre-push = if [ $HG_PATS == "[]" -o $HG_PATS == "['default']" ]; then
               read -p "Really push to default? " -n 1; echo
               [ "$REPLY" == "y" ]
           fi
```

(Here I'm taking advantage of how you can split a long value over several lines by indenting them in a Mercurial config file.)

A push to default looks this

```
% hg push
Really push to default? n
warning: pre-push hook exited with status 1
```

where I typed the `n`. The hooks checks for both no arguments (`$HG_PATS == "[]"`) and a default as the argument (`$HG_PATS == "['default']"`) and will only prompt you in those cases. The `$HG_PATS` variable was introduced in Mercurial 1.6.

PS: I saw you updated the question and asked for a solution in PowerShell, but I'm afraid I know nothing about that language. However, you should be able to lift the important concepts from this answer yourself.

Comment: This is pretty good, but doesn't it completely remove the push ability? I want to be able to push; I just want to make sure that I don't accidentally push to the default.

Comment: mos: You're right... I've updated the answer to let you push again and I've incorporated the best of Ry4an's answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think it's time for me to ask a new question: how to get a powershell command to work in an hg hook.

Comment: Hmm, when I add this to my hgrc I end up getting the warning/prompt regardless of what branch I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer previously posted, in hgrc setting

```
   default-push = .
```

is ALMOST but not quite correct.  It can break, e.g. if you hg your home directory.

Here is the my current BKM to disable default-push:

I've embellished the idea of setting paths.default-push in ~/.hgrc, making it a little bit more self documenting and less error-prone - since, as I point out below, setting default-push = . does not always disable pushing.

in ~/.hgrc

```
[paths]
# my main project master repo
project-master = ...

#DISABLING IMPLICIT PUSH
#     to prevent embarassment from accidentally pushing to the project master repo
#     instead of, in my case, a repo that has fine grain commits
#     that the rest of the team does not want to see in the project master repo
#default-push = .
#     this works mostly, but NOT if you use hg on your home directory
#     since '.' in ~/.hgrc seems to be interpreted as -R ~
#default-push = /NONEXISTENT_default-push_--_must_specify_push_target_explicity
#     this works ok, but I can clean up the error message using blanks
#     keeping this around because blanks in pathnames confuses many UNIX tools
default-push = /'NONEXISTENT default-push -- must specify push target explicitly'
#     this amounts to disabling implicit push targets.
```

Comment: You probably are better off doing that in `.hg/hgrc` (the per-repo hgrc) for your experimental repos rather than in `~.hgrc` (the per-user hgrc).  That's certainly what MG was suggesting above.  When that's the case `.` is perfectly safe.

Comment: ~/.hrc is exactly what *I* want. I clone repos a lot, and it is in these clones, with fresh-made default, that I want to prevent accidentally pushing back to the wrong place.  The problem with doing it in <repo>/.hg/hgrc is that <repo>/.hg/hgrc is NOT propagated by clone.  If you want to use <repo>/.hg/hgrc, you have to install it after every clone.  Now, I *have* written makefiles to do that - hg clone project foo; make -C foo install-hgrc - but (a) I don't think there is a default action after clone, so you have to wrapperize. and (b) other users of the <repo> may not want this.

Comment: By the way, I am very happy with setting default-push in ~/.hgrc.  It has prevented some embarrassment.  However, I still would like to override default completely - because I have fallen into the habit of typing "hg push default". Which is NOT what you want to do when your workflow is to push to a staging area.  Another question, perhaps...