# How to prevent Mercurial repos from being able to pull from specific repos

Tags: mercurial

We've worked out a repository structure we'd like to maintain and under that structure will prevent RepoA from being able to pull from RepoB.  How can I setup a repo so that it can only push to a certain repo but not pull from it?

Comment: Why would you want to be able to push to it, but not pull? Surely being able to pull prior to pushing allows you to perform merges, and hence resolve conflicts?

Comment: Because we never want to be able to write code on our UAT environment, only on our alpha environment.  Preventing full functionality forces this good habit

Answer (score 1):

You can technically push/pull from any location and would probably try to avoid mucking with that flexibility unless you're good at writing [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html).  And, if anyone has write access to UAT, you cannot prevent any changes from being pushed to UAT as you will need to do that when some new bits need to enter the UAT branch for testing.

What it sounds like you are trying to do is preserve a "stable" while allowing work to continue on an "anonymous" branch (your alpha) that was cloned from UAT.  Eventually, you have to merge that back into UAT, so I would really just give a few senior-level developers write access to UAT and trust that they follow the proper procedure when working with the branches.

I suggest reviewing the [Guide to Branching](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/) and the [Managing Releases](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html) section of the [Hg Book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) before trying to invent a new way to seemingly protect your branches.

**Edit:** I did find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302058/can-you-prevent-default-push-but-allow-pull) for preventing the default push, but allowing pulls.  It shows you the basics on implementing a `preoutgoing` hook, which is not what you want, but similar in nature.