# disable/deprecate (but not delete) mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos, mercurial-hook

My colleagues and I use several repositories that live on a centralized (ubuntu, if it matters) server. For several of our projects, we include the same 4 repositories as subrepositories in lots of different projects. This can be a little irritating to constantly be pushing/pulling/merging 4 different subrepositories across lots of different projects because it takes a while to transfer everything over the network, etc.

I would like to combine these 4 repositories into one master repository that can be included in all of our projects going forward. The challenge is that I do not want to delete the old subrepositories as that would break existing projects that are working just fine.

It would be great if there were a way to designate these old repositories as deprecated or, at the very least, make it impossible for my colleagues to push any new changesets to these repositories and display a helpful error message. Is this possible, perhaps with [mercurial hooks](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) as [this tangential Q/A suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302058/can-you-prevent-default-push-but-allow-pull)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't terribly inclined to manipulate permissions with the filesystem because that does not provide a very useful error message to my colleagues. I was able to accomplish this (in mercurial 2.3) with the [prechangeset hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html). First, create a file (.hg/deprecated.py, in this case) to store the hook in the shared repository you wish to deprecate:

```py
# .hg/deprecated.py
import sys
import textwrap

# print out a helpful error message in red to make it obvious things
# are not working
msg = "ERROR: Pushing changesets into this repository is no longer supported. "
msg += "This package has been merged into the /path/to/new/repo repository."
print('\033[%im%s\033[0m'%(31, textwrap.fill(msg)))

# return a non-zero exit code to disallow the changeset to be added to the 
# target repository
sys.exit(1)
```

Then tell mercurial to execute this hook before any changeset is added to the repository by adding the following to your .hg/hgrc file:

```ini
# .hg/hgrc
[hooks]
prechangegroup.deprecate = python .hg/deprecate.py
```

This solution simultaneously alerts the coder that the repository is not active, instructs the coder where the changes should be committed, and prevents the coder from committing code to a deprecated repository. While this isn't as permanent solution as manipulating filesystem permissions, it does instruct people where to find the new repository. Hope someone else finds this useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like [mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/mercurial-server.html), you can just revoke all write access to the deprecated repositories, so that the only permitted operations are pulls or updates.